# move all files and folders within a directory in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-move

I'm trying to move all files and folders within a directory to another location. I thought

```
movefile('D:\path\to\source\*', 'D:\destination\folder')
```

would work, but this gives me an error

```
Error using movefile
The requested lookup key was not found in any active activation context.
```

Comment: That does not look like an error message from built-in movefile. Try "which movefile" and make sure there are no other overloaded variables or functions.

Comment: @Navan: Thanks. `which movefile` tells me it's the builtin the function. I noticed that only files are moved but not folders. I thought the wildcard `*` would move both but it does not seem to be the case. Is there a way to tell `movefile` to move folders as well?

Comment: movefile should move both files and directories when you use *. You need to be careful when using * to avoid recursion if the directory you are moving to is also under current directory.